# How can I send strings between two computers?

Tags: delphi, tcp, chat, communication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Beginner for Delphi Network!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260033/beginner-for-delphi-network)

I'd like to learn how to make two machines communicate, sending and receiving simple strings. The machines might be on the same LAN--or not. I'm talking about something more or less like you'd see in a chat program, I suppose. I understand Delphi, but know absolutely nothing about things like TCP, sockets, ports, etc. Where would you suggest I look to learn these things? ... I know how to use google but, honestly, I'm not totally sure even where to start the search!

Thanks, as always.

Comment: Are you specifically wanting to handle the communications manually as you suggest (ports, sockets, TCP, etc.), or are you just looking for _any_ kind of communication?  For example, hosting a web service on one machine and consuming it on the other?  As for "might be on the same LAN" that tends to make a significant difference.  How the machines _can_ communication will affect how they _will_ communicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner for Delphi Network!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260033/). See also [Which book(s) to learn sockets programming and TCP network communication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122592/)

Comment: Tutorials are out there by the plenty.  Google is your friend.  And the old Indy chat demos should be around on the Indy Sourceforge download page.

Comment: I'd suggest named pipes. This is even what psexec uses to communicate across systems. This answer is one I provided and provides 1 way to do it in Delphi: http://stackoverflow.com/a/360819/12458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for learning how to communicate through sockets the best articles IMO are:

http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/web/socket_programming/socket_programming.html 
http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/web/delphi_socket_architecture/delphi_socket_architecture.html
 (it explain you at a socket level how things are going on)

and

http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htm

as a starter for this kind of things I suggest you also http://delphi.about.com which is a very good resource.

After you understand very well the concepts then you can go to next level and use [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/index.en.aspx), or any other components which make your life easier.

Answer (score 9):

Delphi has shipped with [Indy](http://indyproject.org) for several years now as part of the initial install. If you go to the [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/download/index.en.aspx) project download page (linked to), you'll find a link for several demo apps, one of which is a chat demo.

You didn't specify which version of Delphi you're using, so the demos may or may not need minor changes. If you can't figure them out, you can post specific questions about the problems here (if they're not here already).

Edit: It seems they've dropped the chat demo in recent versions. There's a full chat application (with code) at [Delphi.About](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/aa101105a.htm) that might help (along with several other Indy demos and articles).

Comment: Thanks for the links ... On the Indy (10) download page, the demos look like they're using smtp, pop, imap, and ftp (+ a TCP server/client). Which demo were you pointing me toward?

Comment: Al, read my edit (last paragraph). :)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the `OSI Model` (7 layers), and then read more about each layer, including especially `Ethernet` at the `physical layer`, `TCP` and `UDP` at the `transport layer`, and perhaps `HTTP` at the `application layer`.

The `Indy` library encapsulates things pretty well at the transport layer level using classes like `TIdTCP`, and at the application layer using classes like `TIdHTTP`.